# IDA Xrefs window keep open?

Tags: ida

When I use the context menu "List cross references to", a window opens with a list of all positions found which references the position, and I can double click to a function. But then the window closes, because it is a modal window. Is it possible that it stays open (non-modal) or is there another way to open it again quickly without jumping back and selecting the context menu item again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View - Open Subviews - [Cross References](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/592.shtml)